# Place a SIP call via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, native, sip

I am writing an Android application which will place a SIP call. I want to use the native Android SIP APIs and have found documentation under:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html and
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html

Although I could regsiter with a SIP provider and start a call, it looks like this is too low-level. I want to just hand off the SIP call to the native Android phone app and give it a SIP address to call and assume that the user has already registered a SIP account in the Android phone app.

I thought that there must be an Intent for this, like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL where I could provide a SIP address, like this:

```
Uri phoneCall = Uri.parse("tel:1234567890");
Intent caller = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, phoneCall);
startActivity(caller);
```

but my experiments were unsuccessful. Do I have to use `SipManager` or is there an Intent I could use?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've already created a global SIP-account:

```
Uri phoneCall = Uri.parse("sip:[number]@[domain]");
```

Just replace number and domain with the appropriate values.